# How does javac locate the Java API classes?

Tags: java, javac

The information on [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/findingclasses.html#srcfiles) provides some good hints and general information, but nothing conclusive.

I know that javac.exe basically just launches 'sun.tools.javac.Main' from 'tools.jar' using Java. I also know that the Java API classes are stored in 'rt.jar' in 'jre/lib' under the JDK.  Is this where 'javac.exe' loads the Java API classes from?

I'm wondering about this scenario in particular: suppose I installed jdk1.6.0_17, and later on I installed jdk1.6.0_25.  If I run 'javac.exe' from jdk1.6.0_17, will it load the Java API classes from 'rt.jar' in 1.6.0_17 or 1.6.0_25?

The reason I want to know all of this is I'm in a situation where I know the code I'm compiling is going to run on a particular (not most recent) version of Java, and I want to compile using the same exact version of javac and the Java API to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Isn't there a possibility in your IDE to configure different build scenarios - > e.g. configure two different buiild setups, using the two different JDK versions? I have used that in NetBeans, and I believe it's a functionality offered by Eclipse too. Changing the JAVA_HOME will work, but it will be annoying if you have to do it often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, classes are compiled against the bootstrap(the runtime classes in rt.jar, internationalization classes in i18n.jar, and others) and extension classes of the platform that javac shipped with.So Yes If You run 'javac.exe' from jdk1.6.0_17, will it load the Java API classes from 'rt.jar' in 1.6.0_17 not from 1.6.0_25.

But javac also supports cross-compiling, where classes are compiled against a bootstrap and extension classes of a different Java platform implementation.

See more at : [Cross Compilation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-example) if you want to use

Comment: Good answer, short and accurate. +1!

Comment: Ah, I assumed the API classes were something separate from the bootstrap and extension classes, guess I should have read more closely.  This makes a lot of sense.  Cross compiling might work for me too, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Its pleasure to help you and also thak you G_H. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the desired JDK.  Also change your PATH environment variable to contain the desired JDK bin directory.

Comment: Also note that Java has the notion of a CLASSPATH to resolve shared libs, so op may need to tweak it accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that's gonna have any influence on javac. Some tools, like Ant, use this to figure out a default JDK path. But the asker didn't specify any build tool.

Comment: Ant is involved, but I'm using the `fork` and `executable` properties to force it to launch `javac.exe` as a separate process.  I ran into troubles with Ant trying to launch `javac` from tools.jar,  which is why I'm going to all this trouble.

Comment: @KevinK I think you shouldn't bother with differentiating updates of the same main release. Something compiled with, say, 1.6.0_25 would have to be binary compatible with 1.6.0_17. Actually, I'd sooner compile using the most recent version all the time since it might have more bug fixes and security fixes. The only exception is maybe when some API implementation is updated between versions, like how they went from JAXB RI 2.0.3 to 2.1.3 from update 3 to 4 in JDK 1.6.

Comment: @G_H I understand I'm probably being paranoid here.  The problem started because another developer on the team reported errors during the build; turns out it was because they had installed a Java 7 JDK on their machine, and somehow Ant was running javac from a Java 6 'tools.jar' but trying to load the bootstrap classes from the Java 7 rt.jar.  I'm just trying to ensure a consistent build environment.

Comment: @KevinK Dang, how did they manage to do that? Must've been quite a joy to track that down :D

Comment: Oh yes, bundles of fun :)  The specifics are complicated, but it's partially my fault, I added the Java 6 'tools.jar' to the top of the Ant classpath in the Eclipse launch profile for the build, to force Ant to run javac using Java 6.  I hadn't considered the bootstrap classes, which Ant inherits from Eclipse, and on the dev's machine Eclipse was running using Java 7.